# Como verificar se uma string é None?

Tags: python, string

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
st = ""
if None == st:
   print True
else:
   print False
```

Existe forma de a string `st` ser igual a `None` de forma a escrever no ecrã o valor `True`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tecnicamente, não tem como "uma string ser `None`", pois são coisas diferentes. String (mais precisamente `str`) [é uma classe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str), enquanto [`None` é uma constante *built-in*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#None) que representa a ausência de valor (e cujo tipo é `NoneType`). São tipos diferentes, que você pode verificar assim:

```
print(type('')) # <class 'str'>
print(type(None)) # <class 'NoneType'>
```

O que provavelmente está te confundindo é o fato de que em Python uma **variável** pode assumir valores de tipos diferentes. Por exemplo, uma variável pode ser uma string e logo em seguida ela pode mudar seu valor para um número:

```
s = 'abc'
s = 1
```

Mas isso não quer dizer que a string `'abc'` se transformou no número `1`. Na verdade é o **valor da variável** `s` que mudou de uma string para um [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int).

Por isso, não tem como ver "se uma string é `None`". O que você pode verificar é se **o valor da variável** é uma string ou `None` (ou é uma coisa, ou outra). Ex:

```
s = None
if s is None:
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

O código acima imprime `True`, pois o valor de `s` é `None`. Se bem que, se o objetivo é imprimir apenas `True` ou `False`, bastaria fazer `print(s is None)`.

Agora se você quer testar se uma string é vazia, aí fica assim:

```
s = ''
if s == '':
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

Que também imprime `True` (e que também pode ser simplificado para `print(s == '')`).

---

Existe ainda outra possibilidade (mas depende muito do que você quer fazer). Em um contexto *booleano*, muitos valores são considerados `True` ou `False`, de acordo com as regras do [*Truth Value Testing*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing). Valores como `None` ou a string vazia, por exemplo, são considerados `False`, então você pode ao mesmo tempo testar se é uma string vazia ou `None` assim:

```
s = ''
if not s:
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)

s = None
if not s:
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

O código acima imprime `True` duas vezes, já que tanto a string vazia quanto `None` são valores considerados "falsos", por isso ele entre no `if not s` (lembrando que neste caso ele também vai entrar no `if` se `s` for qualquer um dos valores "falseáveis" descritos na [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), como listas vazias, etc).

Por fim, o `if` acima também pode ser encurtado para `print(not bool(s))` em ambos os casos.

---

Outra opção é verificar o tipo da variável com [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance). Neste caso, só estou verificando se a variável é uma string (mas não necessariamente a string vazia):

```
s = 'abc'
# é uma string, ou None
if isinstance(s, str) or s is None:
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

O código acima imprime `True` se `s` for uma string (qualquer uma, não só a string vazia), ou `None` (e também pode ser encurtado para `print(isinstance(s, str) or s is None)`).

---

Enfim, não ficou claro o que você quer, mas como pôde ver, existem várias maneiras de testar o valor de uma variável. Escolha a que fizer mais sentido para o seu caso (mas tendo em mente que não é a string que pode ser `None`, e sim o valor da variável).

Comment: Acontece que eu tenho função "getsub" e dentro desta, existe um ciclo "for" que a cada iteração devolve um sub-string do género, st[0:9], e a certa altura na funçao main quando chama "getsub" tem um "if" que testa se a sub-string que devolve == None, e ele escreve no ecrã o valor True. Mas eu continuo sem perceber como isso e possível. Já testei varias possibilidades e nenhuma devolve None